# I want to create a scrollable ListView or tableView for a QT / QML Touchscreen Application

Tags: qt, listview, scrollbar, scrollview, qml

I'm going to write a touchscreen application that has a movable listView control. Currently my problem is that the content comes out of the view, if the content is longer/highter than the listView itself when I try to scroll.

[image]

This is my current code. I need a solution only to scroll within the listview and not to overflow its border.

```
ListModel {
        id: listModle
        ListElement {
            name: "Bill Smith"
            number: "555 3264"
        }
        ListElement {
            name: "John Brown"
            number: "555 8426"
        }
        ListElement {
            name: "Sam Wise"
            number: "555 0473"
        }
        ListElement {
            name: "Bill Smith"
            number: "555 3264"
        }
        ListElement {
            name: "John Brown"
            number: "555 8426"
        }
        ListElement {
            name: "Sam Wise"
            number: "555 0473"
        }
    }

    Rectangle {
        x: 100
        y: 100
         width: 180; height: 200

         Component {
             id: contactDelegate
             Item {
                 width: 180; height: 40
                 Column {
                     Text { text: '<b>Name:</b> ' + name }
                     Text { text: '<b>Number:</b> ' + number }
                 }
             }
         }

         ListView {
             id: listView
             anchors.fill: parent
             model: listModle
             delegate: contactDelegate
             //highlight: Rectangle { color: "lightsteelblue"; radius: 5 }
             focus: true
             contentHeight: 150


         }


     }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`listView` exceedes the `Rectangle` parent because there are too many elements to display.

That's perfectly fine, you simply have to turn `clip: true` on your Rectangle object. That way, the content of your list will be visible only from the Rectangle viewport.

**Edit (pro-tip):** if the listview height is **less than** the enclosing parent Rectangle, for usability concerns you should disable the scroll behavior. Look at [Qml Flickable](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtquick/qml-qtquick2-flickable.html) API(especially `interactive` and `contentWidth/Height` ) to perform some simple check ;)

Comment: You're welcome :) Anyway, you should mark the answer as accepted if that's the solution you needed so, if someone else bumps here, he/she will know that.

Answer (score 0):

To implement someting like a scroll index you can use:

```
    ListView.visibleArea.yPosition
```

which gives the Y position in percent.